# What does it mean to "hazard a guess"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I know it's an idiomatic synonym for "make a guess" or "take a guess," but what is the underlying basis for the phrase? Is "hazarding a guess" more dangerous than "taking a guess?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word “hazard” is (probably) from an arabic word meaning “dice”, and came to English through French where it originally meant a game of dice and then more generally chance, randomness. The word further evolved in English to mean risk, then danger. I'll hazard the guess that “hazard a guess” is an idiom that retains the older meaning of “taking a chance on a guess”.

Comment: The game of 'Hazard' came back from the Arab world with the crusaders and ultimately became craps

Answer (score 4):

> **hazard** verb [trans.]
>   venture to say (something): *he hazarded a guess*.

It's like “make a guess”, really. Maybe a bit more uncertain, even.

---

In addition to meaning, I should say that it is very commonly used:

[image: ngram]

Comment: So it's not an idiomatic phrase at all, is it?...Didn't realize `hazard` is actually a defined verb.

Comment: Robert Harvey: I would still consider *hazard a guess* an idiomatic expression. I doubt the verb (in its first meaning) is used in any other context.

Comment: ["I'd hazard that ..."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20%27%20d%20hazard%20that%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) is not unknown, though I wouldn't be surprised if it arose from *hazard a guess*.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by the NOAD, one of the meanings of *hazard* (when used as verb) is "venture to say (something)."

> She hazarded a guess.